# Android - login and relogin

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication, android-intent

in my activity I have login page (L), which leads to hierarchy of activites (L -> A -> B -> C). When user log in, and he goes up to activity C, he minimizes his app and after some while, system will do a force close on this app.

Now, when he start this app again a he log-in, he should have see, where he ware last time an application was running with all opened activities on stack (if he was in C, one back button leads to B, then to A, then to L). How to achive such a behavior in Android? I am now using sharedpreference, which is hodling string of visited activities, then some flag, which tells me whether an app was finished with System close or user close and them I am persisting each activity with its own sharedpreference. If system kills my app, after login I open series of past opened activities in For cycle, but they are on the stack only. They are opened (= onCreate method is run) only when I use back button to see them.

Do you see any cleaner approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want to maintain hierarchy after a force close I bypass the activity stack by replacing each activity with the one that it calls and then override the back event to do the same in reverse.

In ActivityL.java, where you want to go to ActivityA:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

You now just have one activity on the stack - ActivityA. To have the back button behave properly and return you to ActivityL, add this to ActivityA:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityL.class)
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

You'll still need to store enough state information to get you back to the activity where the user was before the force close. In onCreate for ActivityL, check that state info to determine which view you want the user to be on and use code similar to the first block above to go directly there.

This seems a bit cleaner to me than rebuilding the entire activity stack on startup. This does however become more complex if your activities don't follow a strict hierarchy. (i.e. sometimes activity A starts activity B and sometimes it starts activity C).

Comment: THanks, but that means only one activity is remaining on the stack, which is for me inappropriate

Comment: May I ask why? From the perspective of this solution, the stack is just an implementation detail. I maintain a "virtual" stack of arbitrary size with this method and the user experience is indistinguishable from having multiple open activities on the standard activity stack.

Comment: Yes, but it is inappropriate for me, because I will be having quite heavy business application. This is usable, i think, for smaller apps